# Nested OrderedDict to nested list with varying levels of nesting

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, salesforce, ordereddictionary

I am using `simple_salesforce` to query a CRM relational database. The data is queried with `SOQL`, which is a variation of `SQL` specifically for Salesforce.

It returns nested ordered dictionaries. On a "join", if there is no record, it returns `None`. If there is a record, a `OrderedDict` is returned. The loop I have doesn't seem the most efficient as it repeats a few lines. I'm looking for a cleaner way to write the loop.

Query used:

```
select Id, Subject, Account.Name, Opportunity.Name From Case where ID = '500xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict([
    (u'totalSize', 1),
    (u'done', True),
    (u'records', [OrderedDict([
        (u'attributes', OrderedDict([
            (u'type', u'Case'),
            (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Case/500xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        ])
         ),
        (u'Id', u'500xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
        (u'Subject', u"Sample Case 1"),
        (u'Account', OrderedDict([
            (u'attributes', OrderedDict([
                (u'type', u'Account'),
                 (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/001xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
                 ])
             ),
            (u'Name', u'Sample Account 1')
        ])),
        (u'Opportunity', None)]
    )])])


output = []

def get_items(this_item):
   for key, value in this_item.iteritems():
       if key <> 'attributes':
           if type(value) is OrderedDict:
              for key, value in value.iteritems():
                  if key <> 'attributes':
                      record.append(str(value))
           else:
               record.append(str(value))


for item in od['records']:
   record = []
   record.append(get_items(item))


   output.append(record)
print output
```

Output:

```
[['500xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Sample Case 1', 'Sample Account 1', 'None']]
```

Comment: please post expected output

Comment: @MaxU just posted output and desired. Thanks.

Comment: just check the type of `value ` and don't print it if it is `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: @MaxU that will then exclude `'Sample Account 1'` from the output wouldn't it?

Comment: and you don't want/not allowed to specify the record-names: 'Id', 'Subject', 'Account.Name', 'Opportunity' in the script?

Comment: @MaxU Not sure I fully follow, I have all the record-names stored to the `headers` list separately, which I may or may not need, but I am really just after the data itself. Account and Opportunity are tables related to Case so they have an additional level of nesting in the data returned from the API.

Comment: @MaxU, Figured out a way to do this, but looking for a more efficient (DRY coding) way of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
def get_rec_vals(rec):
    ret_list = []
    for key,val in rec.items():
        if key == 'attributes': continue
        if isinstance(val, OrderedDict):
            # recursive call 
            ret_list.extend(get_rec_vals(val))
        else:
            ret_list.append(val)
    return ret_list


output = [get_rec_vals(rec) for rec in od['records']]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[['500xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Sample Case 1', 'Sample Account 1', None]]
```

PS i'm not sure whether it will work properly for multiple records, so you would need to provide at least two records...

Comment: @This worked. It's a pain to provide multiple case examples (as I need to create fake data sets for privacy reasons). I did however try on multiple records and it seems to work fine. Thanks.